# Android Studio, Java, build.gradle for Maven repositories

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I must update my app and I wanna know from someone much more experient than me in Android Studio development if my build.gradles (both) are ok to keep on coding.

```
<html>
<header><title>This is my build.gradle - Project</title></header>
<body>

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}




</body>
</html>


<html>
<header><title>This is my build.gradle  -App</title></header>
<body>

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.elliottwaves.e_waves"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true // this prevents "not mocked" error
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
</body>
</html>
```

There is no Error when I sync Gradle but I can't run the charts yet. It's really new for me. Android Studio, Gradle and Maven differences, etc. My app is on as Beta and some details must be improved in code and even in design assets. So, I'd lovely enjoy somebody's Android Studio experience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you encountered any problems with your build.gradle files? If not, then you shouldn't worry as long as you are following the Android development documentation.

Comment: **DOCUMENTATION** that's it...

Comment: For feedback on code that works, you should check out our sister site [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: I forgot to set apply plugin: 'maven' in app build.gradle file above. I guess some layout instabilities, reported here and on GitHub MPAndroidLib community, come from Gradle/Maven "relationship". I'm still asking....